# How to make an icon and a button have the same id?

Tags: html, css, button

So in my website I have buttons that do a certain function when you click on them. These buttons have a unique ID. When you see the website on a phone, you'll see icons and not the text of the buttons. I did that already. What I want is when you see the icon you're abble to click on it and have it done the same function as the button that has an id. Here's what I've done so far:

```
<div class="map-button-container">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><button id="restaurants" class="map-button">restaurants</button>
      <i class="fas fa-coffee"></i><button id="coffeeshops" class="map-button">coffeeshops</button>
      <i class="fas fa-bed"></i><button id="accomodation" class="map-button">accomodation</button>
      <i class="fas fa-snowboarding"></i><button id="activities" class="map-button">activities</button>
      <i class="fas fa-tree"></i><button id="parks" class="map-button">parks</button>
      <i class="fas fa-glass-martini-alt"></i><button id="bars" class="map-button">bars</button>
      <button id="register" class="map-button">register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not just give the `i` tags a different ID, and then just put that into your JS function (or whatever you're using) alongside the `button` ID?

Comment: Don't attach your event handlers to an ID, attach them to a class, and give the same class to both the icon and the button. IDs must be unique to the document. Classes do not have to be.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can add a Font Awesome icon inside a `<button>`. This way you don't have to worry about extra JavaScript. When user clicks on a button it will do certain action. This is the easiest way.

```
<div class="map-button-container">

    <button id="restaurants" class="map-button">
        <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
        <span>restaurants</span>
    </button>

...

</div>
```

Comment: yes but I styled it so when the screen is small you can't see the button, you only see the icon

Comment: There is a solution for that. For smaller screen just hide text `.map-button span{display:none}` and leave the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your icon inside *button* and the text of button can be in some inline element like `<span>` and on phone you can hide span, in this way click can be applied.

```
<div class="map-button-container">
     <button id="restaurants" class="map-button"> <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i><span>restaurants</span></button>
      <button id="coffeeshops" class="map-button"><i class="fas fa-coffee"></i><span>coffeeshops</span></button>         
      <button id="register" class="map-button">register</button>
</div>
```

The thing is, you will have to style span text and icon to match your previous design as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I added the class of the icon to the function :) it works! Now whether I click on the button or in the icon the function works!

```
 $("#restaurants, .fa-utensils").click(function () {
           var oslo = { lat: 59.9160454, lng: 10.7362453 };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: oslo,
 });
```

Comment: Considering you didn't share this code in the question, no one else could have come up with the answer.